# NSSearchField animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nstextfield, nssearchfield

How to animate an NSSearchField like the one in Reeder for Mac : http://juliensagot.fr/upload/reederSearchAnimation.mp4

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of using

- an `NSViewAnimation` to move the icon right-to-left,
- a second `NSViewAnimation` to fade in the search field?